# Is every invariant subspace has an expression of certain form with respect to Primary-Cyclic Decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Fix a linear space $V$ over $F$ and a linear operator $T$ on $V$, we know that we can decompose $V$ into Primary-Cyclic subspaces(in the sense of direct sum). Suppose we fix such a Primary-Cyclic decomposition$$V = W_1 \oplus \dots \oplus W_n$$where all the $W_i$ are primary-cyclic(i.e. indecomposable), is it true that every invariant subspace of $T$ is a sum of some of these $W_i$?

We know that since $$primary \& cyclic \iff indecomposable,$$in some sense the Primary-Cyclic decomposition is the "finest" decomposition. The above question I've been thinking about generates naturally from the intuitive expectation of "fine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily the case that all invariant subspaces can be written as a sum of $W_i$. For instance, consider
$$
T = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc} 
0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0
\end{array} \right]
$$
with cyclic decomposition
$$W_1 = \{(x_1,x_2,0,0):x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb F\}, \quad 
W_2 = \{(0,0,x_3,x_4):x_3,x_4 \in \Bbb F\}.
$$
The invariant subspace $\ker(T) = \{(x_1,0,x_3,0): x_1,x_3 \in \Bbb F\}$ cannot be written as a direct sum of $W_i$.

Comment: I see, this is indeed a very straight-forward counter example. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @penseur You’re welcome! You can decompose the space like this, however, if we have the stronger hypothesis that the subspace is $T$-admissible, as defined on page 7 [in this pdf](http://www.sci.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~mate/misc/cyclic_decomposition.pdf)